# Parse Saving Conflicts

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, parse-platform, conflict

I am working on an iPhone app that basically opens up polls and allows users to vote on different options in a poll such as "Agree" or "Disagree." I am using Parse to manage my data.

When a user votes it uses a class I made on Parse called "Vote" with the voter's username. It then adds that vote instance to an array that stores all of the votes for that poll.

**The problem: (explained as simple as possible)**
Let's say there are 2 iPhones and one poll. Each iPhone retrieves the same poll from parse. Each iPhone now has the same poll (PFObject) stored locally on their device and can now view it. iPhone 1 votes on the poll adding 1 vote to the array on votes. iPhone 2 does the same. So now iPhone 1 has the same poll stored on it's phone but with an array that only has it's vote. iPhone 2 has the same poll stored on it's phone but with an array that contains only a vote representing itself. So now iPhone 1 saves the PFObject for that poll to Parse. So on Parse there shows 1 poll with 1 vote from iPhone 1. But now iPhone 2 saves the poll it has stored locally as a PFObject to Parse and basically overwrites the other array so now only iPhone 2's vote shows up.

So my question is, how can I stop this conflict between multiple devices with Parse?

Does Parse just not have a good way to handle arrays being edited by multiple devices at the same time? Or is there something additional I must do to avoid this.

No code should need to be attached I am doing this the normal way the Parse Docs show.

**Just to lay out the database structure though:** 
A class called Poll has an NSArray that stores Vote objects.
Vote objects contain a user's username.
Vote objects are a class made in Parse so of course are just PFObject's in code.

I am doing this in Objective-C not Swift by the way.

Comment: How many polls are you talking?

Comment: @Hyperion 1 poll multiple votes.

Comment: Just the one poll.  So why not make a whole new class for it "Poll", with columns for each piece of info you want, then every client adds a new line with themselves

Comment: I'm sure there's a way to solve your concurrency problem, but if not that could serve as a work-around

Comment: @Hyperion There is a class called Poll and one of it's columns is called "Votes" it's just an NSArray to store each vote. I'm not sure what you mean exactly?

Comment: Well in total are you planning to have a large number of polls

Comment: You are much better off creating a separate record per-vote as @Hyperion suggests.  Create a class that has a pointer column for user, a pointer column for poll and a vote value - then each vote is saved as a new record and your concurrency problem goes away.  Aside from `incrementKey` Parse doesn't have any locking or atomic updates

Comment: @Hyperion Yes but for the sake of this example and testing there is only one. If you are asking if there will be a lot of polls when the app is actually in use the answer is yes. Sorry, I didn't mean there would only ever need to be one poll.

Comment: @Paulw11 I see what you're saying but then wouldn't this take a much longer amount of time to load votes for one poll? I mean you would have to go through every vote for every poll that exists to find what vote is for what poll which would probably be very inefficient.

Comment: It is a pretty simple query, based on a single key value - the poll.  The only real issue is that a single query in Parse is limited to 1000 results, so if you had more than 1000 votes then you would need to issue multiple queries with paging to get the total result set, but you are going to struggle to deal with the concurrency if multiple users are updating a single object

Comment: Yeah, what @Paulw11's saying.  Sorry, I wasn't making much sense

Comment: @Paulw11 Alright I may try that thanks. However I will need to be prepared for more than 1000 votes. How can I issue multiple queries with paging? I'm not sure what you mean by that. Or maybe it would be better if I saved each vote to the user itself and when a poll is loaded it just goes through each user retrieving the votes like that? This way I wouldn't have to worry about exceeding 1000.

Comment: Remember with Parse you pay based on the number of requests/per second (above 30/sec anyway) - a single query that retrieves 1000 rows is one request.  1000 queries that each return 1 user is 1000 requests.  Paging is pretty straight forward- You can set `limit` and `skip` on the `PFQuery`, so set the limit to 1000.  If you get less than 1000 results you are done, if not issue the next query with skip=1000, rinse, repeat increasing skip each time

Comment: @Paulw11 That makes sense I think I know what to do from here thank you for your help!